# Segmentation fault in OpenSuse

Tags: segmentation-fault, opensuse

I'm having trouble running FullProf Suite on my laptop.
  [FullProf download link](https://www.ill.eu/sites/fullprof/php/downloads.html)

It was working fine two days ago, now i can launch the program but everytime i run the WilPlotr app I get this error message

```
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
winplotr-2006      0000000000D5E989  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
winplotr-2006      0000000000D5D300  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
winplotr-2006      0000000000CD6392  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
winplotr-2006      0000000000C83D33  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
winplotr-2006      0000000000C8A0BB  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libpthread.so.0    00007FF89511F890  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libXt.so.6         00007FF896CC9380  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
winplotr-2006      0000000000A8DB29  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
winplotr-2006      0000000000A8F973  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
winplotr-2006      0000000000A2D8AB  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
winplotr-2006      0000000000A2D4F6  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
winplotr-2006      0000000000A25CCE  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
winplotr-2006      00000000004A1986  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
winplotr-2006      00000000004DADD5  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
winplotr-2006      0000000000419146  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc.so.6          00007FF894D8AB05  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
winplotr-2006      0000000000419039  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

I have a machine running on OpenSuse 13.2

```
G-YAHIA@linux:~> uname -r
3.16.6-2-desktop
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a bug in the program. SIGSEGV means that it tried to access memory that is not available. Contact the authors if you don't have access to the source code.

Comment: No answer has been sent by them for now, but how is it possible that it was working fine and now no more?